# "Member" won't recognize the members of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm experiencing a very curious problem. I have a list named "theorems" that has exactly one item. Here's proof:

```
[]> theorems
(((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))))
[]> (car theorems)
((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED)))
```

Clearly ((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))) is a member of the list "theorems." But when I test it for membership, it fails:

```
[]> (member '((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))) theorems)
NIL
```

But if I call it explicitly, it works:

```
[]> (member (car theorems) theorems)
(((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))))
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp uses `EQL` as the default test function. `EQL` checks whether the items are the same identical items. You want to test whether the items have the same structure. So you need to use `EQUAL` or `EQUALP`.

```
CL-USER 11 > (setf theorems '(((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED)))))
(((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))))

CL-USER 12 > (member '((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))) theorems)
NIL
```

Tell `MEMBER` to use `EQUAL`:

```
CL-USER 13 > (member '((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED)))
                     theorems
                     :test 'equal)
(((ROSES ARE RED) ^ (~ (ROSES ARE RED))))
```